# Error: Child compilation failed: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve [file path]

Tags: npm, terminal, filepath

When I try `npm run start` I get the below error. It's a file path issue and I'm having trouble figuring it out.

```
Error: Child compilation failed:
  Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users/Dylan/Desktop/Programming  /Projects/Remote Tech Jobs/remotetechjobs/src/index.html' in '/Users/Dylan/Des  ktop/Programming/Projects/Remote Tech Jobs/remotetechjobs':
  Error: Can't resolve '/Users/Dylan/Desktop/Programming/Projects/Remote Tech Jo  bs/remotetechjobs/src/index.html' in '/Users/Dylan/Desktop/Programming/Project  s/Remote Tech Jobs/remotetechjobs'
  EntryModuleNotFoundError: Entry module not found: Error: Can't resolve '/Users  /Dylan/Desktop/Programming/Projects/Remote Tech Jobs/remotetechjobs/src/index.  html' in '/Users/Dylan/Desktop/Programming/Projects/Remote Tech Jobs/remotetec  hjobs'
```

webpack.config.js file

```
const path = require('path');
const HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');

module.exports = {
entry: ['babel-polyfill', './src/js/index.js'],
output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'src'),
    filename: 'js/bundle.js'
  },
  devServer: {
    contentBase: './dist'
  },
  plugins: [
new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
    filename: 'index.html',
    template: './src/index.html'
    })
  ],
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader:'babel-loader'
        }
      }
    ]
  }
};
```

file path in my text editor
[image]